# no cmake vs compiler found for msversion: 4 (windows7)

Tags: .net, cmake

apppium-doctor shows `opencv4nodejs cannot be found`. So I try to install `opencv4nodejs` with `npm -g install opencv4nodejs`. But I got this error:

```
info install opencv version: 3.4.6
info install with opencv contrib: yes
info install custom build flags:
info install
info install executing: git --version
info install git --version: git version 2.22.0.windows.1
info install
info install executing: cmake --version
info install cmake --version: cmake version 3.15.0
info install
info install CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
info install
info find-msbuild failed to find vs2017 via powershell: unexpected powershell output
info find-msbuild attempting to find msbuild via registry query...
info find-msbuild trying the following msbuild paths:
info find-msbuild version: 4, path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
info find-msbuild version: 3.5, path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\msbuild.exe
info install using msbuild: { version: 4,
info install   path:
info install    'C:\\Windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319\\msbuild.exe' }
ERR! Error: no cmake vs compiler found for msversion: 4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! opencv-build@0.1.4 install: `node ./install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

I got cmake v3.15 from https://cmake.org/download/. What does log mean? How can I install `opencv4nodejs` properly?

Answer (score 6):

Try this: npm install --global windows-build-tools --vs2015

Answer (score 5):

Try: `npm install -g windows-build-tools` before `npm install opencv4nodejs`